# Regular expression works in .NET but not javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regular expression to validate phone numbers and it works fine via c# but when I try and implement it in my client-side Javascript validation it fails with the error "unexpected quantifier".  I have seen several posts that mention look behinds/look a heads but i`m unable to resolve the problem.

My regular expression is:

```
^\+?([0-9]+[ -]?){5,}[0-9]+$
```

Does anyone know what the problem is ?

Comment: What is your input and how do you use in C# like replace, match?

Comment: in c# it is being used with a regex validator.

Comment: There is nothing that looks like a lookbehind/ahead, no need for this to validate a phone number actually.

Comment: Show a complete JavaScript example so that people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: these are valid patterns :123456789
+123456789
123 456 789
123-456-789
+123 456-789
01909 550111

Comment: You should rather update your question.

Comment: I can't get any error running your regex in the console (http://d.pr/i/hFhp+). It seems to be working fine.

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/y7D8Z/

Comment: If you are using it in a string, use backslash to escape \

Comment: @Jamiec Of course it works, no need for a fiddle to check that. See the answer below.

Comment: @wared - speak for yourself, you dont need to construct a javascript regex from a string, and if you decide not to it still works. A jsfiddle example helps to explain what *I* did to check what the problem might be.

Comment: @Jamiec "dont need to construct a javascript regex from a string", indeed, in this particular case, but this is not the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doubling the backslash. If you construct your regex from a string, `\+` will become `+`, which, directly after `^`, would indeed be an unexpected quantifier.

```
^\\+?([0-9]+[ -]?){5,}[0-9]+$
```

Comment: even with an escape character the regex engine will take it as a quantifier?

Comment: @rps: No, then it will treat it as a literal plus sign. Another way of making the `+` a literal would be to enclose it in a character class: `[+]`.

Comment: then why are you suggesting to use `\\\`?

Comment: @rps Check by yourself with and without double backlash : `new RegExp('^\+?([0-9]+[ -]?){5,}[0-9]+$')`.

Comment: @rps: Oh, I misunderstood your question. What I meant with my answer is that *if you construct the regex from a string*, you need to double your backslashes, because otherwise the string processing engine will strip it away before the regex engine gets to see it.

Comment: My mistake, skipped that _If you construct your regex from a string_ and jumped to the expression in your answer, for a second I thought I was gonna learn another new fact about regex!

Comment: thanks that works. I would also like to allow an empty string as valid input (no spaces)  how would I do this ?

Comment: You could make everything between the anchors optional: `^(\\+?([0-9]+[ -]?){5,}[0-9]+)?$`.

Answer (score 1):

It *does* work, at least it does [on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/kD5bP3). The only unexpected quantifier I can think of, is the `\+` at the beginning. You may need to double escape that, like so: `\\+`. Once to get the backslash into the string, and once again for the actual escape.

The backslash is a common escape character. In this case, it's not just an escape character in your regex, it's an escape character in your string as well — the string you use to represent your regex.
When that string is parsed, a backslash is encountered. That means the parser is on alert that the following character may be a special character — for instace `t` for a tab or `n` for a newline. Instead, a `+` is found, which has no special meaning to the string parser, so the escape is discarded and the `+` is put into the string. This means that if try to put `^\+?([0-9]+[ -]?){5,}[0-9]+$` into your string, your string will wind up containing `^+?([0-9]+[ -]?){5,}[0-9]+$`.
Then that is parsed as a regex. That parser sees a `+` — a quantifier — without anything to quantify. Hence the error.

Now if you try to put `^\\+?([0-9]+[ -]?){5,}[0-9]+$` into your string, when parsing that, a backslash is encountered, which puts the parser on special character alert, after which another backslash is found. The parser knows that `\\` means "put a backslash in the string" (just as `\t` means "put a tab in the string") and your string winds up being `^\+?([0-9]+[ -]?){5,}[0-9]+$`.
Then the regex parser does it's work, it encounters a backslash and knows that a backslash means that the following special character should be used as a literal character.

---

But, as you can see in the example I gave, it may not quite do what you expect it to.
You're matching an optional +, then 5 or more times (one or more digits, followed by an optional space or hyphen), followed by one or more digits.
This means it matches `1234 12 12 345-1234 1213`. Is that really what you're looking for?